# Python unit test patch failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-requests

So I was following this youtube video:

https://youtu.be/6tNS--WetLI?t=1973

When I replicate what is done in the video, my test fails:

Class:

```
import requests

class JetpackRebooter:

    @staticmethod
    def reboot_jetpack(secure_token):
        response = requests.post('http://my.jetpack/restarting/reboot/', data={'gSecureToken' : secure_token})
        return response.status_code
```

Unit test:

```
from src.jetpack_rebooter import JetpackRebooter
from unittest.mock import patch

def test_reboot_jetpack():
    secure_token = 'ca26bacf85c6d69d0bdaa3ff07df3cc4118abf45'
    with patch("jetpack_rebooter.requests.post") as mocked_post:
        mocked_post.return_value.status_code = 200
        assert JetpackRebooter.reboot_jetpack(secure_token) == 200
```

*However*, changing `patch("jetpack_rebooter.requests.post")` to `patch("requests.post")` causes the test to pass. Why is this?

Comment: What about `patch("src.jetpack_rebooter.requests.post")`?

Comment: Yup that did the trick... Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`patch("jetpack_rebooter.requests.post")` does not work because the module's full import path is not `jetpack_rebooter`, but `src.jetpack_rebooter`.

Because of that, `patch("src.jetpack_rebooter.requests.post")` would work.

However, as `src.jetpack_rebooter.requests` points to the `requests` module object, there is no difference between `patch("src.jetpack_rebooter.requests.post")` and `patch("requests.post")`; but there *would* be a difference between `patch("src.jetpack_rebooter.requests")` and `patch("requests")`.